# Matching multiple values in wp_usermeta to get email from wp_users table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have created a simple html form to submit two values, license plate # and state, to a php script I have written. I am using wordpress. I want the script to look up a user in the wp_usermeta table, and select the user ID which has meta_value entries which match both license_plate and state submitted in the form. I then want the script to look up the email of that user in the wp_users table. Here is the code I have:

```
$license_plate = $_POST['license_plate'];
$state = $_POST['state'];

$userInfo = $wpdb->get_row  ( $wpdb->prepare ("
    SELECT user_id, user_email
    FROM $wpdb->usermeta um
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->users u ON (u.ID=um.user_id)
    WHERE meta_value = %s", //OR meta_value !!
    $license_plate
));
```

So far I can get the user_email based on the license_plate meta_value, but I want to make sure the related user_id also shares the same state value, since my database several users with the same  license plate # but different states.

How can I amend this query to satisfy both of these conditions?  Or do I write an additional query?

Comment: Are you storing the `state` and `license plate #` in `usermeta`? What are the corresponding `meta_key`?

Comment: yes, they are both stored in usermeta. the key for license_plate is license_plate and state is state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query,

```
$wpdb->prepare ("SELECT u.id, u.user_email
FROM $wpdb->usermeta plate, $wpdb->usermeta state, $wpdb->users u
WHERE plate.user_id = state.user_id
AND plate.meta_key = 'license_plate'
AND state.meta_key = 'state'
AND u.ID = plate.user_id
AND plate.meta_value = %s
AND state.meta_value = %s", $license_plate, $state)
```

Here is the SQLFiddle for the same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbc58/3

Comment: @user3068211 - Ok, we need to troubleshoot that... try passing a hardcoded license_plate and state in the above query like `...plate.meta_value = 'some plate no.' AND state.meta_value = 'some text'` Ensure that these plate numbers and state combination exists.

Comment: Also check if the SQL Fiddle I have given actually correspond to your scenario. Because this query clearly works in the fiddle

Comment: Yes, the SQL Fiddle does correspond to my scenario.  I've set my script to print the query, after storing it in a variable.  This is what I've got:

`$userInfo = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ("SELECT u.id, u.user_email
FROM $wpdb->usermeta plate, $wpdb->usermeta state, $wpdb->users u
WHERE plate.user_id = state.user_id
AND plate.meta_key = 'license_plate'
AND state.meta_key = 'state'
AND u.ID = plate.user_id
AND plate.meta_value = %s
AND state.meta_value = %s", $license_plate, $state
));
 
echo  $userInfo;`

The server is just printing 'array'

Comment: This now works, after prefacing your query with $wpdb->get_row.

Comment: Thanks @hashbrown, you have and will always be the 'perfect code' to complete a morning.